# How to upgrade jersey from version 2.17 to 2.35?

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

I am working on a legecy product which is using jersey 2.17 and have been asked to update to jersey 2.35.

What are all the pre-requisite thta needs to be taken care of while upgrading to version 2.35?

The project is ant based, so its not a simple mvn pom.xml upgrade, i will be manually replacing the jars in WEB-INF folder. So what is the best approach and what are the issues to look out for when performing such upgrade.

Comment: Read the release notes of the versions in between. `ant` can be used in 1000 ways, so there is no way to tell what you need to do.

Comment: See the [migration guide](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/migration.html) if it helps

Comment: Thanks for the guide, it helps a lot! Just a follow up, i see in the migration guide they do not explicitly mention migration from 2.17 to 2.35. So does it mean we cannot directly migrate from 2.17 to 2.35 and have to move up in staged manner due to lot of deprecations and changes? Or direct jump is still fine?

Comment: All the migration steps mentioned between versions 2.17 and 2.35 apply.

Comment: Oh! Since this is a ant project, i had to directly update from 2.17 to 2.35 , will go through the migration guide. Thanks a lot this helps!